# How to use CameraX without XML and PreviewView in service or Receiver?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I want to take photo with CameraX in service without any xml and PreviewView or something else for showing picture, But I have problem.

Comment: put some code and describe your problem, currently this question is waaay to broad...

Answer (score 1):

The CameraX use cases (Preview, ImageAnalysis and ImageCapture) are all completely independent.

Bind only ImageCapture to the lifecycle without any Preview that requires PreviewView. It will work.

Comment: I can confirm that

Answer (score 0):

You should use Camera2, this question is mistake

Answer (score 0):

To access the camera you'll probably have to use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services).

It isn't clear what you're trying to do with the camera from your question, but if you're trying to capture a photo, you'll need to set up the camera inside your service and use the [ImageCapture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture) use case.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a customer service to extend LifecyleService class like below: (cameraSelector and ImageCapture)

```
public class cameraService extends LifecycleService {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       
       RunCameraX();
       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    RunCameraX() {
       ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
       //select-usecase
       //Camera facing, image analysis & no preview
       Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector2,imageCapture );
     }

     imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback () {
            @Override
            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //todo
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
}
```

Build.grade should have dependency declared,

```
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
```

And declare this service in Manifest file

```
<service
        android:name=".cameraService"/>
```

Comment: How is this showing the preview though?